# Boot Time properties like JPA is not loaded using external hosted configuration (via REST) in springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to run a very basic SpringBoot crud application using an externally hosted server to contain configurations. For this I implemented **PropertySourceLocator** interface. Implementation below

```
@Component
@Order(0)

class CustomHeaderPropertySourceLocator implements PropertySourceLocator {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private final HttpHeaders headers;
    private final String configServerUrl;
    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableEnvironment configurableEnvironment;

    public CustomHeaderPropertySourceLocator() {
        this.configServerUrl = "";
        this.headers = new HttpHeaders();
        this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    }


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        PropertySource<?> customPropertySource = locate(configurableEnvironment);
        configurableEnvironment.getPropertySources().addFirst(customPropertySource);
    }

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> locate(Environment environment) {
        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            String url = "";

            HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);

            // Logic to handle response
            MapPropertySource propertySource = new MapPropertySource("externalPropertySource", flatProperties);
        
    }
```

Now all runs well and good till I am not connecting to a database. I am able to fetch the config via @{Value} notation and use it in an API.
But when I try to connect to a DB, because JPA is being initialised before this happens, I get connection error as it is not able to read the database config properties due to the config not fetched.

Now this can hamper anything that requires params to be present at runtime. How do I make sure that this runs before anything and works as seamlessly as spring cloud config does?
Please consider that I can't use spring cloud config for this.